# Internet Explorer no longer prompts to save username and password - why?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, autocomplete

I have an HTML login form.

I have made some code changes to this area of functionality and Internet Explorer no longer prompts to save the username and password entered.

It did so before my changes.

I have looked at the difference in HTML and the only difference I can see is that the ordering of DOM element attributes has changed.

What might I be doing wrong?

The form currently looks like this:

```
<form class="forms">
    <h1 class="sc-cgHJcJ dmPBnn"><span>Enter your login details</span></h1>
    <div class="sc-gzOgki gSqehT">
        <label class="sc-iyvyFf fQeNdL" for="username"><span>Username</span></label><input type="text" class="sc-iLVFha eZKzJz sc-hwwEjo iVXrBC" name="username"  autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" aria-label="username" id="username" placeholder="Your username (e.g. email address)">
        <div class="sc-kPVwWT gARmdw" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sc-gzOgki gSqehT">
        <label class="sc-iyvyFf fQeNdL" for="password"><span>Password</span></label><input type="password" class="sc-iLVFha eZKzJz sc-hwwEjo iVXrBC" name="password"  aria-label="password" id="password" placeholder="Your password">
        <div class="sc-kPVwWT gARmdw" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sc-dYzWWc kcnzuR">
        <div class="sc-jtHxuu ktTqKC">
            <div>
                <button class="sc-laTMn fjNFUg" type="submit">
                    <div class="sc-hGoxap fqiECM">
                        <div class="sc-eilVRo gqpUjK">
                            <div class="sc-eerKOB cTmMQZ">
                                <div class="sc-emmjRN fOCeSR">
                                    <div class="sc-dymIpo boXqhR sc-cpmLhU bBvrRk"><span class="sc-bnXvFD kDfNZW sc-gisBJw eyFjZA">4</span></div>
                                    <div class="sc-fhYwyz iPvpet sc-cpmLhU bBvrRk"><span class="sc-jzgbtB duATCd sc-bnXvFD kDfNZW sc-gisBJw eyFjZA">4</span></div>
                                    <div class="sc-gFaPwZ dFjfQf"></div>
                                    <span class="sc-gJWqzi ccEJEu sc-bnXvFD kDfNZW sc-gisBJw eyFjZA">4</span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="sc-rBLzX goLDfH sc-bnXvFD kDfNZW sc-gisBJw eyFjZA">D</span><span class="sc-bMvGRv jcNXtO sc-bnXvFD kDfNZW sc-gisBJw eyFjZA">E</span><span class="sc-CtfFt drWCKK sc-bnXvFD kDfNZW sc-gisBJw eyFjZA">4</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sc-fjmCvl cDDtAg">
                            <div class="sc-TFwJa cisZhm"><span>Login</span></div>
                            <div class="sc-TFwJa Ydfnv"><span>Logging in</span></div>
                            <div class="sc-TFwJa Ydfnv"><span>Logged in</span></div>
                            <div class="sc-TFwJa Ydfnv"><span>Login</span></div>
                            <div class="sc-TFwJa Ydfnv"><span>Error</span></div>
                            <div class="sc-TFwJa Ydfnv"><span>Error</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div><span class="sc-fOKMvo idczDY"><a aria-label="Forgotten Password" href="/forgotten-password"><span>Forgot your password?</span></a></span></div>
        <div class="sc-blIhvV hoftyp"><a class="sc-dUjcNx bHTXTB" aria-label="Create account" target="_blank" href="https://www.hivehome.com/register" rel="external noopener"><span>Create Account</span></a></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but are you sure [you haven't answered the prompt with 'No' once](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/force-internet-explorer-save-passwords)? Also; Which version of IE?

Comment: IE11/Windows 7. Yes I am confident I have always dismissed the prompt with the "X" - switching between builds of my application causes the prompt to appear (before my change) and not appear (after my changes).

Comment: Well, I cannot find much about this. There might be external factors why it doesn't work: SSL cert. missing, mixed content, page is framed, etc. I cannot tell without actually having access to the login page myself.

Comment: Thank you. It is being served over plain HTTP (no TLS).

Comment: And it always was, I presume? Anyway, why not test it on another computer? That's always a good idea. :-)